# How to make two raster images with different column and row values the same?

Tags: raster

I need to use two raster maps that contain exactly the same number of rows and columns to generate a relationship (For example scatter plot of Evapotranspiration (ET) and EWTcanpoy in my study area. For now, two raster images do not have the same number of rows and columns.

For example, I have 211 columns and 142 rows in the ET raster image and 1009 columns and 490 rows in the EWTcanopy raster image.

However, I adjusted my cell values same for both layers (x,y with 0.00416666667) each and it is the [image]same for both layers. But I have different columns and rows in rasters.

How can I make both in to a same level.

Please see the attached doc for the raster information that I have.